# Linux Mint 15 - Unable to connect to wireless

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, internet

I have been using Linux Mint 12 for some time and I remember I had faced similar problems back then but that had been fixed by doing some research. However, this time around with the upgrade to 15, I just cannot get it to work.

I have the Asus u56e-BBL5. There are several people who get this problem on this model I can't find the solution. I have looked at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1929304) and [this](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=117773) . The problem is that I can see all the available wifi networks and when I enter the password for my home network, it just tries to connect for a bit and then I get a notification that 'wireless disconnected'. I don't even get a connection when I do the wired connection.

On trying this: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` , I get `FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.`. Nothing has worked as of now. This is definitely not a hardware problem because everything works fine on my Mint 12 setup on the same machine.

Comment: I have the same issue with my Thinkpad SL410.

Comment: Have you tried setting it up the normal linux/unix way? i.e. for WEP using iwconfig etc and for WPA using wpa_supplicant? Just asking cause I did and that failed too, even tho the same params work fine on my slackware distro.

Comment: I forgot this was still here and not solved. I eventually got it to work and I think `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` did work. Just had to do something (that I can't remember) to solve the `FATAL` problem.